# SailsJs add custom task in default.js

Tags: node.js, sails.js, grunt-contrib-cssmin

I'm trying to add a custom task in a salsjs application.

This is what I've done so far:

- Added a new file in the task/config directory named cssminTemplates.js
- Modify the default.js file in the task/registerd directory.

My cssminTemplates.js is basically a copy of the cssmin.js standard file:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

 grunt.config.set('cssminTemplates', {
    dist: {
        src: ['asset/templates/above_the_fold.css'],
        dest: 'asset/templates/above_the_fold.min.css'
    }
 });
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-cssmin');
};
```

default.js file as been modified as follow:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
 grunt.registerTask('default', [
  'compileAssets',
  'linkAssets',
  'cssminTemplates',
  'watch']);
};
```

But when I start the app with sails lift command I got this error:

```
Warning: Task "cssminTemplates" not found.
```

I try to change the 'cssminTemplates' with 'cssmin' and I've got no errors.

Answer (score 0):

In `Grunt.js` ([ref](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/anatomy/my-app/gruntfile-js)), `cssminTemplates` function is invoked instead of [`cssmin`](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-cssmin/blob/master/tasks/cssmin.js) which is loaded via `grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-cssmin');`. This is where the function is invoked:

```
function invokeConfigFn(tasks) {
    for (var taskName in tasks) {
        if (tasks.hasOwnProperty(taskName)) {
            // Invoking the function....
            tasks[taskName](grunt);
        }
    }
}
```

In other words, you are setting the function (`cssminTemplates`) and invoking it from `Grunt.js` but Grunt loaded `cssmin` instead via `loadNpmTasks()`. I think that's why setting `cssminTemplates` does not work.